# How do you hydrate a result with Native Query in Doctrine2?

Tags: php, sql, orm, doctrine-orm

I need to use a native query, because I need to `ORDER BY RAND()` and it's currently not possible (afaik) even with custom function.

However, if I use native query, I need to explictly set the column to fetch to allow an Object Hydration, and you may guess, I've a lot of column, so it's kinda boring to set it all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use `ORDER BY RAND()` even in native query, you should use

`SELECT rand() as rand,* .... ORDER BY rand`

I think it is quite possible with doctrine

Comment: clever, thank you, however why sould I never use such query? Is it about perfomrance?

Comment: yes when you use order by rand() mysql recalculates the order each time a new row is fetched because for each row rand() returns different number. It have a huge impact on performance, while in the other case it calculates rand() only once and then orders the results only once.

Comment: ok thank you for the explanation, it works well with doctrine